# HP Proliant DL360 G6

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant

I am working on a HP Proliant DL360 G6 Server.. When I boot it up, it shows the first screen, then a command was prompted that the Server will shut down in 5 seconds, due to Processor Fan failure.. When i checked the SID, two fans were indicated red light. Then I was not able to find the right parts for it, so I got CPU processor fans from G5 server, when I plugged the G5 Fans, it won't work. The voltage on the G5 is 12V which is the same specs on G6 fans. Then I put back the good fans from the G6, it was not able to work. When I tried the replaced G6 fans on another good working G6, they were able to work.Please advise on what to do..

Answer (score 1):

Get the right part.

This server needs all four of its fans in a dual-CPU configuration. It can run with three fans but will fail to boot with only two fans.

You clearly have a few of the correct part, so use the *Spare Part Number* ([532149-001](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=532149-001&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=532149-001&tbm=shop)) printed on the label of one of the surviving fans to search for a replacement. They're not expensive.

Anything beyond this is just standard troubleshooting. If you have a bad system board, you may have to call HP for support or a replacement.

[image]

Comment: The server is booting (at this current time) as regular boot up but it stops r and counts down 5 seconds and you can hear beeping sound then after the beep, it shuts down.. plus, keep in mind that when i tried the fans on another server, they do work.

Comment: Then process of elimination... You may have a motherboard issue. Or maybe there's a problem with the fan socket. You need three operational fans. Do whatever it takes to get a functional solution.

Comment: please assist me if you can on the motherboard specs and pics online.. the exact one to be precise. i hope i can get the server up and running.. On the issue of motherboard, when I turn the server on, it goes through all the boot up process but without fans spinning, so it just gets to the booting for a while then prompts that it will shut down in five seconds. do you have any idea on what else might have caused.. any other alternate ideas on the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Parts from another server won't work.  Even parts from another G6 server won't work.  Sometimes parts from another DL360 G6 won't work.  You will have to buy the right fan and replace it.  Very few workarounds in this case.

What you are experiencing is the fan pin-out.  If you randomly started placing other fan parts in the server you may have shorted out the fan header (little red light on the mother board).  If the fan header is blown, no fan you put in there will work.  This is unlikely, but it is possible.

No way to post the server without fans in that generation.  Later generations give a bit more flexibility.

As a side note... try to hook up the iLO and look at what it says.  You will get tons of information in the IML log viewable from the iLO webpage.